# scrapy : How to scrape <ul> <li>

Tags: html, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm learning how to scrape using scrapy api.

I would like to scrape the text into the `<h2 class >` and the the link into `<a href >` but it's not working (the attached file)

[image: html page]

I tried to extract the text in `<a >` tag

```
import scrapy

class PriceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "annonce"  #name of spider

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/ile_de_france/?th=1',

        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for annonce in response.css('section.tabsContent li').extract():
            yield{
                'title':annonce.css('a ::title').extract_first(),
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try. Your css selector is heavily flawed.

```
import scrapy

class PriceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "annonce"  #name of spider

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/ile_de_france/?th=1',

        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for annonce in response.css('.list_item'):
            yield{
                'link':annonce.css('::attr(href)').extract_first(),
                'title':annonce.css('.item_title::text').extract_first().strip(),
                }
```

One more thing. Open your `settings.py` file and make it:

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```